# Вытащить два первых символа из строки

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

Есть такая таблица в несколько колонок [image: [1]]

И есть вот такой код

```
request.on('data', function(login){
    data = decodeURIComponent(login);
    var exec = new require('child_process').execFile;
    exec('C:/tmp/scriptdb.bat', function (err, stdout){ 
            data1 = stdout.toString();
            var fs = require("fs");
            fs.writeFile("C:/tmp/data2.txt", (data1), function(){});    
            console.log(data1.toString());
            dataf = (data.slice(3));
            if(data1.includes(dataf))
        console.log('есть совпадение')
            else
        console.log('нет совпадений')
        }
    );
```

Клиент на странице кликает на свой логин, который посылается в переменную data.
Далее скрипт проверяет есть ли пользователь с введённым логином в таблице.

Как из строки с логином вытянуть те первые две цифры из столбика "usr" и вывести их в консоль?

Comment: `Split(full_line_readed_from_file)(1)`.

Comment: простите, а может информацию о пользователях стоит хранить не в текстовом файле?